How to Dynamically Adjust Rate Limits Based on Concurrent Connections in Nginx?
I am currently facing a challenge with dynamically adjusting rate limits in my Nginx configuration based on the number of concurrent connections to my web server.
Problem Statement:
I have set up a rate limit of 10 requests per minute for connections under 20 concurrent connections. If the concurrent connections exceed 20, I want to gradually reduce the rate limit. Specifically, for every 10 additional concurrent connections, I want to decrease the rate limit by 1, down to a minimum of 2 requests per minute (Maximum 100 concurrent connections).
Below is my Nginx configuration file for reference. I have initially set a rate limit of 10 requests per minute and added a custom error page for when the rate limit is exceeded:
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=10r/m;
    upstream myservers {
        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        server 127.0.0.1:8082;
        server 127.0.0.1:8083;
        server 127.0.0.1:8084;
    }

    server {
        listen 8081;
        root /data/site1;
    }

    server {
        listen 8082;
        root /data/site2;
    }

    server {
        listen 8083;
        root /data/site3;
    }

    server {
        listen 8084;
        root /data/site4;
    }

    server {
        error_page 503 /error.html;
        location = /error.html {
            root /data/errors;
            internal;
        }
        
        location / {
            limit_req zone=mylimit burst=20 nodelay;
            proxy_pass http://myservers/;
        }
    }
}

events {}

Challenges:

Measuring Concurrent Connections: How can I measure or retrieve the number of active concurrent connections in Nginx?

Dynamically Adjusting the Rate Limit: How can I programmatically reduce the rate limit as the number of concurrent connections increases, and ensure it stops reducing when it hits 2 requests per minute?

Simulating High Load: What can I do to simulate high concurrent connections (e.g., 30 simultaneous connections) for testing purposes? Currently, I use curl with unix watch command to send requests at 1-second intervals.



What I Have Tried:

I have researched but found it difficult to locate relevant information about dynamically adjusting rate limits in Nginx.
Formulating the steps and approach is challenging for me as I am new to Nginx.

Thank you everyone.

http {
    lua_shared_dict my_shared_dict 1m;
    init_by_lua_block {
        ngx.shared.my_shared_dict:set("rate_limit", 10)
    }

    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=lowlimit:10m rate=10r/m;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=midlimit:10m rate=5r/m;
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=highlimit:10m rate=2r/m;

    upstream myservers {
        server 127.0.0.1:8081;
        server 127.0.0.1:8082;
        server 127.0.0.1:8083;
        server 127.0.0.1:8084;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;
        location /nginx_status {
            stub_status;
            allow 127.0.0.1;  # Only allow local access
            deny all;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            access_by_lua_block {
                local http = require "resty.http"
                local httpc = http.new()
                local res, err = httpc:request_uri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/nginx_status", {
                    method = "GET"
                })

                if not res then
                    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Failed to request nginx status: ", err)
                    return ngx.exit(500)
                end

                local active_connections = tonumber(string.match(res.body, "Active connections: (%d+)"))
                local zone

                if active_connections < 20 then
                    zone = "lowlimit"
                elseif active_connections < 60 then
                    zone = "midlimit"
                else
                    zone = "highlimit"
                end

                ngx.var.limit_zone = zone
            }

            set $limit_zone "lowlimit";
            limit_req zone=$limit_zone burst=20 nodelay;
            proxy_pass http://myservers;
        }
    }
}


Would be so happy if you could provide an explanation.
